# how to redirect url by namecheap?

Tags: url, redirect, hidden

When my customers click on buy, they are redirected to a bank's checkout. I want the url displayed to be mine and not from the bank.
Is there any way to do it?
I use namecheap

I do not have access to the hosting of the bank's website

I haven't tried anything